# Cannot delete a dir via SSH: etc/rc.d/init.d/functions': Operation not permitted

Tags: ssh, centos, mediatemple, rm

I am attempting to delete a backup directory on MediaTemple's (dv) via SSH. The directory is "old" and contains the entire server contents from OS level that (mt) backed up there after my server was hacked.
I want to remove it in case there's any malware etc there that could compromise the server again. It is not permitting me though:

cannot remove `old/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions': Operation not permitted

I tried rebooting the server and retrying the delete but still same.

Comment: Are you the root user?

Comment: What does `ls -lZ old/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` say? `lsattr old/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions`?

Comment: ls -lZ old/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
-rwxr-xr-x  root root                                  old/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working as root and this happens then there may be extended attributes set on the file. Have a look at the output of

`lsattr /old/rc.d/init.d/functions`

if you get an output containing an `i`

```
----i-------- /old/rc.d/init.d/functions
```

then the file is imutable and cannot be deleted. To remove the `i`

```
chattr -i /old/rc.d/init.d/functions
```

Comment: Hey Iain, it did have an 'i' in the attributes, so I removed as you described but still would not permit deletion:

`sattr old/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions`
`-----a------- old/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions rm -rf old
`rm: cannot remove `old/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions': Operation not `permitted
`

Comment: @Jay: check  the `/old/rc.d/init.d` for the `i` flag and remove it if it's there. It may be an idea to run `chattr -R -i /old`

Comment: Thanks Iain - I just removed the ----a------ also which was causing the file to be un-deletable!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are working as root? If so, try to explicitely set ownership and permissions for the whole tree and then try the delete again:

```
  chown -R root old
  chmod -R u+rwx old 
  rm -rf old
```

Comment: What should I set the permissions to?

Comment: See my edit, this is a real broad sweep, but should help. Be real careful though that you only affect the `old` directory.